# Twitter share error Sharekit-ios

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

i added sharekitkit my project. And wrote code like here :
    `SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yatanadam.com"] title:@"ali"];
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];`

And my ShkConfig file:
`#define SHKTwitterConsumerKey      @"9ga4eUQVVHtpj3U4UPosQ"

```
    #define SHKTwitterSecret            @"r43dw1kQyCB3AGs1vDai6C7wCxUhQlIIKr0rp5vU"
#define SHKTwitterCallbackUrl       @"https://www.google.com"
 #define SHKTwitterUseXAuth         0 // To use xAuth, set to 1
#define SHKTwitterUsername          @""
```

when  i pushed my sharetwitter button an activityindicator is seen. an 2 seconds later it is disappear and nothing else. doesnt share on twitter.

edit:i really need help boys. i am working with this issue nearly 12 hours. i am getting crazy now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShareKit hasn't been maintained in over a year.  You might want to checkout http://www.getsocialize.com which is a good alternative to ShareKit.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to Issac, (I cannot reply directly due to rep)

ShareKit **is** in fact still around and actively maintained. The original developer stopped maintaining it, but the community took over. You can find it here in github https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit